# Regex just keep the content between tags but select everything

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

So in VS Code I used this `<script>(.|\n)*?<\/script>` regex pattern to select everything between `<script>` tags (including tags) and it worked great. (See the example below)

```
<html>
<p>dsldsdsd</p>
<p>dsldsdsd</p>
<p>dsldsdsd</p>

*<script>
Some code
</script>*

 *<script>
Some code
</script>*

<p>dsldsdsd<p>
<p>dsldsdsd<p>

</html>
```

So with this `<script>(.|\n)*?<\/script>` everything between * * gets selected.

Now what I actually want to do is do the opposite of what I've shown you. For example, like this. Select everything else but leave inside`<script> </script>`tags. (Along with the tag)

```
*<html>
<p>dsldsdsd</p>
<p>dsldsdsd</p>
<p>dsldsdsd</p>*

<script>
Some code
</script>

<script>
Some code
</script>

*<p>dsldsdsd</p>
<p>dsldsdsd</p>

</html>*
```

So I went through some regex documents online and I tried the following regex to select everything else (and keep everything between `<script>` tags)

```
^((?!<script>(.|\n)*?<\/script>).)*$
```

But this just keeps the word `<script>`. What have I done wrong?

In short, what I'm trying to do is negate the `<script>(.|\n)*?<\/script>` expression.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: if you don't show  an example we have to guess whet you mean with negate. If in the end you want to have two (2) parts of the file selected it will not work with 1 regex. You have to write an extension that will invert the current selection, select the `script` tag and content and then invert the selection, what do you want to see if there are 5 `script` tags in the file

Comment: At least your negative lookahead works for me. If your script tag is still selected, ensure that you don't use the global flag.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comments. I've updated the question with more info. The issue is when I try to negate with ^((?!<script>(.|\n)*?<\/script>).)*$ it just leaves the opening <script> tags in VS code and select everything else.

But what I'm trying to do is the exact opposite of what I've shown in the first example.

Comment: Does this have to be vscode? You could invert the match with standard `grep`

Comment: Hi, yes I'm doing it with VSCode as I'm editing bunch of HTML files.

Comment: Another solution, you can select the entire text and then replace your regexp result by empty string.

Comment: It is easily done in Notepad++ as its engine is Boost and it contains conditional replacement pattern. See [this YT  video of mine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OWXm-yZUoK0). With VSC, you will probably get what you need with two passes: 1) `(<script>([\w\W]*?)</script>)|[\w\W]` => `$1\n` and then 2) `\n{2,}` => `\n`.

Comment: why don't you have closing tags on `<p>`

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The reason I can't use empty strings method is that I have different script content between script tags. They are not the same.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor for the Notepad++ suggestion. I got it done using Notepad++.

Comment: So notepad++ is ok but standard grep isn't? Ok...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An idea is to [match what you don't want **but capture what you need**](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick) to `\1`

```
<script>[\s\S]*?<\/script>|((?:<(?!script)|[^<])[\s\S]*?)(?=<script|$)
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yWTBnw/2)

To not skip over an opening `<script` in the alternation either match a character, that is not `<` or match a `<` which is not followed by `script` by use of a lookahead until `<script` occurs or `$` end.